# Find the unique values in a python string variable and separate with a comma, for a SQL criteria

Tags: python, pandas

Morning,

I need to retrieve the unique elements in a string which will be used as part of a SQL criteria.

```
sales_code_string_RFQ =  'AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','AAA','EEE',.......
```

Goal is to get a unique list of sales codes from `sales_code_string_RFQ` separated by a `,` The following works but seems to be inefficient. Any suggestions to improve?

```
# Covert string to list
sales_code_string_RFQ = sales_code_string_RFQ.split(',')
print('2. Split sales_code_string_RFQ:')
print(sales_code_string_RFQ)

["'AAA'", "'BBB'", "'CCC'", "'DDD'", "'AAA'", "'EEE'".....]

print('3. Get unique values and convert to list:')
sales_code_string_RFQ = list(set(sales_code_string_RFQ))
print(sales_code_string_RFQ)

["'AAA'", "'BBB'", "'CCC'", "'DDD'", "'EEE'".....]

print('4.Covert list to string:')
sales_code_string_RFQ = ",".join(sales_code_string_RFQ)
print(sales_code_string_RFQ)
print("", end='\n')
```

Final correct output:

```
'AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD',  'EEE' ,....
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the exact output you're trying to acheive? Is it a list of strings, just one string? I can help you with this problem, so please clarify that for me.

Comment: A string (sales_code_string_RFQ) with all duplicate entries removed. Each element separated by a comma. Note sales_code_string_RFQ is not a list

Comment: ok so list function removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of sales codes like this:

```py
sales_codes = ["'AAA'", "'BBB'", "'CCC'", "'DDD'", "'AAA'", "'EEE'"]
```

The built-in Python class `set` will sort the list for you and take only unique items from it:

```
unique_codes = set(sales_codes)
```

Then you can join them together to form your query criterion:

```
criterion = ', '.join(set(sales_codes))
```